# How to convert csv to hierarchial json

Tags: python, json, d3.js, hierarchical-data

I have a csv file which is of the form:

```
Category Sub-Category Value
 A            A1        1
 A            A2        2
 A            A3        5
 B            B1        10
 B            B2        3
 C            C1        2
 C            C2        2
 C            C3        3
 D            D1        5
```

I need to convert it into json (hierarchial) to do some d3.js visualization. So, I need to get this in the form

```
{
 "name": "AllData",
 "children": [
  {
   "Category": "A",
     "children": [
      {"Sub-Category": "A1", "Value": 1},
      {"Sub-Category": "A2", "Value": 2},
      {"Sub-Category": "A3", "Value": 5}]...
```

How do I go about doing this? I'm not very well versed in javascript. I'd prefer something in python.

Comment: You go in two steps, (1)read your csv into an array, and (2)transform the array grouping in categories. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just been able to convert from the csv to a json. still working (and struggling) to get the hierarchy part.

Comment: this second part is also a two step movement (1) from array of objects to object of arrays and (2) sorting and grouping the array of objects. Which step do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
import json
f = open('path/to/file','r')
arr=[]
headers = []

for header in f.readline().split(','):
headers.append(header)



for line in f.readlines():
lineItems = {}

for i,item in enumerate(line.split(',')):  
lineItems[headers[i]] = item


arr.append(lineItems)

f.close()

jsonText = json.dumps(arr)

print jsonText
```

The [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520165/python-convert-csv-file-to-json).