# Python csv to json (D3)

Tags: python, json, csv, d3.js

I was trying to create a JSON file(for D3) from a .csv which i have generated as follows:

```
uat,soe1.1,deploy-mash-app40-uat,3.8.2.8,org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline,mashonline-ui-static
uat,soe1.1,deploy-mash-app22-uat-has,1.0.1.RC1,org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline,realtime_balances_mims_feeder
stg,soe1.1,deploy-coin-app2-stg,1.1.2,org.mbl.coin.ui.visormobile,vm-web-ui
stg,soe1.1,deploy-coin-app2-stg,1.2.14,org.mbl.coin.ui.factfind,factfind-web-ui
```

Tried several approaches, including almost all posts in StackOverflow.
The D3 JSON which i would like to have is like this :

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "uat",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "soe1.1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-mash-app40-uat",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "mashonline-ui-static",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "com.cgl.bfs.mas.mashonline",
                                            "size": 3938
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "3.8.2.8",
                                            "size": 3812
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-mash-app22-uat-has",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "realtime_balances_mims_feeder",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.0.1.RC1",
                                            "size": 3534
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "com.cgl.bfs.mas.mashonline",
                                            "size": 5731
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "stg",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "soe1.1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-coin-app2-stg",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "vm-web-ui",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.1.2",
                                            "size": 3812
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "com.mbl.coin.ui.visormobile",
                                            "size": 6714
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "factfind-web-ui",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.2.14",
                                            "size": 5731
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "com.mbl.coin.ui.factfind",
                                            "size": 7840
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, have a the last two column values as the siblings of a column 4.
Thanks in advance (I am a newbie to python as well).

Tried
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102344/how-to-convert-csv-to-hierarchial-json)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520165/python-convert-csv-file-to-json) and a lot of other links, but no way i could make it work

The code I have it running is as follows (thanks to one of the above links) but  am finding it difficult to add the "name", "children" node when reaching a cell.

```
import json
import csv

tree = {}
name = "name"
children = "children"
reader = csv.reader(open("cleaned_new_test.txt", 'rb'))
reader.next()
for row in reader:
    print tree
    subtree = tree
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell:
            if cell not in subtree:
                subtree[cell] = {} if i<len(row)-1 else 1
                print subtree
            subtree = subtree[cell]

print json.dumps(tree, indent=4)
```

Comment: D3 can also read csv files if that helps [see here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)

Comment: Where are you getting `size` from?

Comment: @jedwards  The size is just a value  I am adding randomly just to conform to the format of D3. Doesnt have any meaning as such now.

Comment: @RúnarBerg thanks but it seems D3 doesnt offer help in formatting csv to our own custom formatted json.

Comment: Can you verify that the json you wrote is the json you want -- specifically, the structure of the second "half" of the output is different from the first.  And `org.mbl.coin.ui.factfind` looks like it's duplicated.  In the first half, you have columns 4 and 5 as descendants of column 6.  In the third entry, you have columns 4 and 6 as descendants of column 5.  In the last entry, you have columns 5 and 6 as descendants of column 5.

Comment: @jedwards the format is correct as the whole file lists out the deployments in various environments and the same artifact can be available in multiple environments. 

Basically the format of csv is :
environment, server-type, container-name,artifact-version,artifact-name, artifact-common-name.

I think i can change the csv to a better format so that building the dictionary becomes easier :

environment, server-type, container-name, artifact-common-name,artifact-version,artifact-name
uat,soe1.1,deploy-mash-app40-uat,mashonline-ui-static, 3.8.2.8,org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline,

Comment: But the conversion from your sample csv to your sample json is inconsistent.  Re-read what I wrote.  There's no clear logic to your conversion.

Comment: @jedwards
My bad, corrected it.
Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: @gameshark thanks for updating your json.  See my answer for an approach that generates a json that may suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get from your csv file to the json:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

def fmt(d):
    l = []
    for (k,v) in d.items():
        j = OrderedDict()
        j['name'] = k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            j['children'] = fmt(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for (k,v) in v:
                j[k] = v
        l.append(j)
    return l

# Build OrderedDict
d1 = OrderedDict()
with open('input.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, )
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        # Extract the columns you want to use as "leaves"
        leaves = [row[-2], row[-3]]
        for l in leaves: row.remove(l)
        # Build a dictionary based on remaining row elements
        ctx = d1
        for e in row:
            if e not in ctx: ctx[e] = OrderedDict()
            ctx = ctx[e]
        # Re-insert leaves
        for l in leaves:
            ctx[l] = None

print(json.dumps(d1, indent=4))
print('---')


# Insert missing items (ctx = context)
ctx = d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app40-uat']['mashonline-ui-static']
ctx['org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline']   = [('size', 3938)]
ctx['3.8.2.8']                      = [('size', 3812)]

ctx = d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app22-uat-has']['realtime_balances_mims_feeder']
ctx['1.0.1.RC1']                    = [('size', 3534)]
ctx['org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline']   = [('size', 5731)]

ctx = d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['vm-web-ui']
ctx['1.1.2']                        = [('size', 3812)]
ctx['org.mbl.coin.ui.visormobile']  = [('size', 6714)]

ctx = d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['factfind-web-ui']
ctx['1.2.14']                       = [('size', 5731)]
ctx['org.mbl.coin.ui.factfind']     = [('size', 7840)]

# Wrap "formatted" in another dictionary
d2 = {"name": "flare", "children": fmt(d1)}

j = json.dumps(d2, indent=4)
print(j)
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "flare", 
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "uat", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "soe1.1", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-mash-app40-uat", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "mashonline-ui-static", 
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline", 
                                            "size": 3938
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name": "3.8.2.8", 
                                            "size": 3812
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-mash-app22-uat-has", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "realtime_balances_mims_feeder", 
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline", 
                                            "size": 5731
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.0.1.RC1", 
                                            "size": 3534
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "stg", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "soe1.1", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "deploy-coin-app2-stg", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "vm-web-ui", 
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "org.mbl.coin.ui.visormobile", 
                                            "size": 6714
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.1.2", 
                                            "size": 3812
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "name": "factfind-web-ui", 
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "org.mbl.coin.ui.factfind", 
                                            "size": 7840
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name": "1.2.14", 
                                            "size": 5731
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It's not the prettiest, but it gets the job done.

Some notes:

- Adding the `size` elements after the fact is ugly, there might be a better way to do this.  (I'm referring to the code that starts with the comment "Insert missing items").  In this section, you can specify additional key:value pairs to add as a list (key,value) 2-tuples.
- This section could have been written as:

  ```
  # Insert missing items (ctx = context)
  d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app40-uat']['mashonline-ui-static']['org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline']              = [('size', 3938)]
  d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app40-uat']['mashonline-ui-static']['3.8.2.8']                                 = [('size', 3812)]
  d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app22-uat-has']['realtime_balances_mims_feeder']['1.0.1.RC1']                  = [('size', 3534)]
  d1['uat']['soe1.1']['deploy-mash-app22-uat-has']['realtime_balances_mims_feeder']['org.cgl.kfs.mas.mashonline'] = [('size', 5731)]
  d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['vm-web-ui']['1.1.2']                                               = [('size', 3812)]
  d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['vm-web-ui']['org.mbl.coin.ui.visormobile']                         = [('size', 6714)]
  d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['factfind-web-ui']['1.2.14']                                        = [('size', 5731)]
  d1['stg']['soe1.1']['deploy-coin-app2-stg']['factfind-web-ui']['org.mbl.coin.ui.factfind']                      = [('size', 7840)]
  ```

  (without the `ctx` reference stuff).  I just used defined `ctx` to be a position in the dictionary structure, then used that to set the deeper dictionary values, to make the lines shorter and more manageable.
- The expected json much better, but still a bit off.  Namely, you specify identifiers like `com.cgl.bfs.mas.mashonline` but your csv has `org.cgl.bfs.mas.mashonline` ("com" vs. "org").  Also, the order of the "leaf" elements in your json is inconsistent.  In the json my script outputs, column 5 appears before column 4.  In your json, the first element appears this way, but the last three appear with the order swapped (4 before 5).  If you want this swapped order, change:

  ```
  leaves = [row[-2], row[-3]]
  ```

  to

  ```
  leaves = [row[-3], row[-2]]
  ```